# how do I curl a sparql syntax query

Tags: curl, sparql

I have following **http call** that works fine when issued in a browser

`http://sparql-playground.sib.swiss/sparql?query=SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {  ?s ?p ?o} LIMIT 10`

However I can't get this to work in `curl`.

Can someone explain where to put the quotation characters, possible escape characters etc. that are needed for this?

I work in windows by the way

Comment: this is cURL basics, it's a simple `GET` request - and there is also no need to do the URL encoding manually: `curl -G http://sparql-playground.sib.swiss/sparql --data-urlencode query='SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o} LIMIT 10'` - indeed, you could also provide the URL encoded query. Or perform a `POST` query, or ... it's pure cURL. For other resultset formats you have to change the accept header indeed

Comment: Not a regular curl user and syntax can be daunting. occasionally.  Thanks for the syntax, it works provided the single quotes are replaced with double quotes as it is windows like I said.  
Thanks

Comment: Ok,if you found the solution you might want to post it here as an answer and then even click on "accept" to mark it as resolved?